# How to read and get the C5.0 Model out of R

Tags: r, machine-learning, c5

I've searched and search but can't find the answer.  I have a c5_model trained and ready but I needed to do 100 trails to get it working to the level I want it to.  But I'm stuck on trying to get it out of the model in R.  I have done a summary but how do I get the decision tree out.  Which trial do I want to use?
[image]

Update:

I'm building the model by doing the following

```
control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                    number = 5, 
                    repeats = 3, 
                    classProbs = TRUE, 
                    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)
grid <- expand.grid( .winnow = c(FALSE), 
                 .trials=100, 
                 .model="tree" )
c5_model <- train(HasFraud ~ .,data = train, method = "C5.0",trControl = control,metric = "ROC",tuneGrid = grid,verbose = FALSE)
```

Is this the wrong method to train the model?

Comment: please do not post images of your code or data.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I needed to do 100 trails to get it working to the level I want it to"?  Were you adjusting the parameters each time? Or were you just trying to get an idea of the variation in the accuracy?  Why 100 trials?

Comment: 1. Sorry about the image, got frustrated trying to paste.
2. I set trails = 100.  I did 100 trials because it was the max.  and yes I was trying to get an idea of the variation in accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

An object of class `C5.0` has a number of elements, as described in the help file you can pull up with `?C50::C5.0.default`.  One of those elements is `tree`.  If you've assigned the output of a call to `C5.0()` to a value, say `model`, you can extract any of its elements using the `$` operator. For example:

```
model <- C5.0(<the call you made that generated the model>)
model$tree
```